# jquery accordion not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, accordion

So this jquery accordion isn't working in IE 8 but works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. What gives?

Here is the fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/jEeqQ/

Here is script links and code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( ".blurb, .contributors" ).accordion({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
    </script>
<script>$(document).ready(function($) {

    $( ".blurb, .contributors" ).on( "accordionactivate", function( event, ui ) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(".ui-accordion-content").offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
</script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".blurb" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active:false
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="blurb">
        <h3></h3>
        <div>
            <div class="text_center full left padding">
                <h1 class="uppercase">#fridayfacts</h1>
                <h6>Join us on twitter every friday</h6><br>
                <h6 class="text_center"><a class="button" href="https://twitter.com/rcumsu" target="_blank">@rcumsu</a></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="text_left full right">
                <h6>Fact:</h6>
                <div class="text_left padding half left">
                    <p>The US needs 34% more students in STEM to keep up w/ economic demand. CTE helps meet that need.</p>
                    <p>Too many MS students drop out, often because they don't see real-world value of a degree. With CTE, they connect learning to work.</p>
                    <p>13K people with 4-yr degrees have re-entered MS community colleges to gain job skills. CTE prepares them for a profession.</p>
                    <p>20M+ in the US are un/underemployed, yet 3.4M jobs are unfilled due to skills gaps. CTE gives students the skills they need to find work.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="text_left padding half right">
                    <p>Employers value real-world, hands-on job experience. With CTE, MS students gain this experience early and qualify for more jobs.</p>
                    <p>STEM ed is crucial to US competitiveness in technology. CTE helps get kids in those fields faster. </p>
                    <p>By 2018, the US will need 22 million associate or higher degrees to fuel the economy. With CTE, MS students will be ready.</p><br><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .blurb, .contributors {
    /*
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 0;*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-viewport .blurb {
    bottom:-15px;
}
.blurb_padding {
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.ui-accordion {
    height:0;

}
.ui-accordion-header {
    font-family: 'BrandonGrotesqueMedium';
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1.5px;
    line-height:12px;
    padding:26px;
    background:#FBAF39;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 64px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index:9999;
    }
.blurb .ui-accordion-header {
    width:60px;
}
.contributors .ui-accordion-header {
    width:150px;
}
.ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header.ui-accordion-header-active.ui-state-hover {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:#FBAF39;
}
.ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header.ui-state-hover{
    background:#DDDDDD;
    color:#777C76;
}
.ui-accordion-header-active {
    background:#fbfbfb;
    color:#FBAF39;
    }
.blurb .ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header:after {
    content:"extra";
}
.blurb .ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header.ui-accordion-header-active:after {
    content:"close";
}

.contributors .ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header:after {
    content:"contributors";
}
.contributors .ui-state-default.ui-accordion-header.ui-accordion-header-active:after {
    content:"close";
}

.ui-accordion-content {
    background:#FBAF39;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:90%;
    padding:3% 5% 55px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.ui-accordion-content a.button {
    background:#fbfbfb;
    padding:13px;
    line-height:12px;
    color:#FBAF39;
}
.ui-accordion-content a.button:hover, .ui-accordion-content a.button:active {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#FBAF39;
}
.ui-accordion-content h6, .ui-accordion-content .lowlight, .ui-accordion-content .highlight, .ui-accordion-content .midlight, .ui-accordion-content h1 {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ui-accordion-content p, .ui-accordion-content .text {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ui-accordion ul {
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Tienne'; font-weight: 400;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 18px;
}
.ui-accordion .icon {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

There is some custom jquery on there to add some scrolling when accordion opens very tall on mobile.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As a friendly suggestion, if you're going to use things like `-webkit-transition`, be sure to include the vendor prefixes for Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera (and the unprefixed version too, last). Deliver a consistent experience when possible ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jquery library to a higher version like 1.8.3 and it works unless you specifically require 1.7.1

I have updated fiddle you gave ...does not work for 1.7.1 in IE8 but works in 1.8.3 in IE8

`<script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js></script>`

Updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jEeqQ/10/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use jQueryUI acordion method before loading jQueryUI itself.
Load if just after jQuery and it will work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( ".blurb, .contributors" ).accordion({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

even i had same problem.but i solved that problem using these Instructions.

Instructions
1

Load Internet Explorer 8 from the "Start" menu or desktop and browse to the Google Chrome Frame website. Click on the "Get Google Chrome Frame" button and click the "Accept and Install" button after reading the terms of service. Let Internet Explorer 8 download Google Chrome Frame and click the "Close" button after the installation finishes.

2

Click the "Start" button and type "regedit" on the "Search programs and files" text box. Press the "Enter" key on your keyboard to launch the registry editor. Expand the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" folder and double-click the "Software" folder appearing under it. Right-click the "Google" folder inside "Software" and point to "New." Select "Key" and type "ChromeFrame" without quotes.

3
Right-click on an empty space within the right panel of the Registry Editor and select "New." Select "DWORD Value" and type "AllowUnsafeURLs" without quotes. Double-click the "AllowUnsafeURLs" entry and set the value data to "1." Click the "OK" button and close the Registry Editor.

4
Restart Internet Explorer 8 and open the page that has problems with jQuery. Click the Internet Explorer 8 address bar and place the text cursor before the "http://" text. Type "gcf:" without quotes or spaces and press the "Enter" key to fix the jQuery problems.

: 
i think it will help u

Comment: TLDR; your answer is use Chrome?

Comment: Chrome Frame is no longer supported by Google - http://www.google.com/chromeframe/about/

Comment: This is not a solution to the question